# how to do http get with django

Tags: python, django, rest, http-get

This should be one of the simplest things, but I can't find how to do it in the documentation.  I have found how to do it python lib2, but I would like to do it with django to get back a status code, content, etc.

Something like:

```
response = httpget('http://my-ulr.com')
print response.status_code
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This functionality is not part of Django (since the framework is designed mainly to *serve* request and not to *make* them), but Django is just Python - you can use Python's built-in [urlib2 library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html), but I would strongly suggest using the excellent [Requests library](http://www.python-requests.org).

*Requests* is really fun to work with, and you can't say that about *urlib2*. You can even say *Requests* is quite *djangish* in its simple beauty, and it's creator Kenneth Reitz is an active member of the Django community. But anyways - *djangish* or not, it works great and you can use it in any Python code.

With *Requests* your example code would look like this:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('http://my-ulr.com')
print(response.status_code)
```